# Pull the latest remote git branch incrementally without worrying about merges

Tags: git, git-pull, git-clone

How do I do incremental downloading of just the changed files from remote repo without worrying about conflicts? I want any local changes to be discarded and overridden. Also, because the repo lives on Google Drive, it's important that no unchanged files are touched.

Comment: Ok. But I'm not sure why you think we need to know that... Do you have an actual question, and does it have something to do with programming?

Comment: There are lots of git questions on Stackoverflow. I've just posted one yesterday and it was upvoted. Do you think git questions don't belong here?

Comment: @twalberg, I edited the question. Do you like it better now?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I do incremental downloading of just the changed files from remote repo without worrying about conflicts?

If I understand your question correctly, you want to update your local working copy to match an upstream repository and you want to discard any local changes.  You could first do this:

```
git remote update
```

This will pull down changes from your remote repository (/repositories), but will not update your working directory.

Then you can run:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This will reset your local branch to match exactly the `origin/master` branch.  If your local branch is not named `master` then changes names as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How does it differ from "git stash; git pull"? Other than the obvious fact that git stash creates a stash.

Comment: `git stash` followed by `git pull` will preserve any local history you have, and may still result in merge conflicts if you have committed changes since you last synchronized with the upstream repository.  `git reset` discards any local changes.